# Em uma url de API, oque significa "scope"?

Tags: vb.net

Estou trabalhando em cima de uma API da Slack utilizando o vb.net para programar. Na página do site há como montar a url de requisição dos metodos da API, porém em um dos parâmetros está destacado: "Requires scope: channels:read".
Este é meu código atual:

```
     Dim oRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest

        oRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://slack.com/api/channels.list?token=" & oAccessToken.access_token & "&exclude_archived=1")
        oRequest.Method = "POST"
        oRequest.UserAgent = "Aplicação"
        Dim httpResponse As HttpWebResponse = oRequest.GetResponse()
        Using streamReader = New StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
            Dim result = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
            Console.WriteLine(result)
        End Using
```

Desta maneira retorna o seguinte JSON:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "missing_scope",
    "needed": "channels:read",
    "provided": "identify,bot"
}
```

Esta é uma das páginas onde contém informação sobre a API: https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.list
Utilizando o WebRequest como posso encaixar este "Channels:read" que aparenta estar faltando?

Answer (score 0):

Essa API requer autenticacao OAuth.

No OAuth um scope é um agregado de recursos. Para obter acesso a esses recursos o usuário tem que confirmar que lhe consede acesso ao scope correspondente.

Por exemplo: Nas aplicacoes android a maior parte das aplicacoes pedem-lhe autorizacao para aceder á internet.

O conceito é exatamente o mesmo no OAuth. [No caso da slack pode ver os scopes aqui](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-scopes)

Teria entao que fazer um pedido para

```
https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=...&scope=channels:read
```

[Veja a seccao oauth da Slack](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth)